# cache.match returns undefined in my react js pwa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

caches.match returns undefined and delete my stored cache or my cache is being deleted for any reasons and cache.match can't match anything

i'm trying to make a working pwa, i register the service worker directly on my index.html and it succeeds, and my service worker for the moment have only this

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'version-1'

const urlsToCache = [
    'index.html',
    'static/js/main.a1ae2d16.js',
    'service-worker.js',
    '/manifest.json',
    '/logo192.png',
    '/favicon.ico',
]

const self = this;

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then((cache) => {
                console.log('Opened cache')
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache)
            })
    )
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(cache => {
                console.log(cache)
                cache.match(event.request.url, {ignoreVary: true})
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response)
                        if (response) {
                            return response
                        }
                    })
            })
    )
})
```

the install event is working as expected, on my first time in the page it store in cache the listed requests, but when i refresh the page, in the fetch event occurs an error because the respondWith gets a undefined, because my cache.match returns as resposne in my callback an undefined (always) even if in the previous load of the page i saw the request stored in cache, also when i log cache it's an empty object and when i look into my stored cache again it's now empty, i don't know if it's being cleaned for any reason when i reload the page or if the cache.match don't match anything and respondWith broke the page and the cache because it receive an undefined

sorry for my grammar, if i forget to explain something useful please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `'/'` to the cached routes.

Also you should return a fallback value like `fetch(event.request.url)`.